# SFML Sockets seem to connect but when the data is extracted it is random symbols. C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, sfml

I'm trying to send data from one program to another on the same PC using SFML sockets and packets. I've followed the online tutorials correctly I think so it might be something unrelated to my code but thought I'd check to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

My server code is this

```
sf::TcpListener listenerSocket;
    if (listenerSocket.listen(1000) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        //error
    }

    sf::TcpSocket clients[2];

    while (true)
    {



        if (listenerSocket.accept(clients[0]) == sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            std::cout << "A client has joined the queue\n";
            std::cout << "There are now 1 clients\n";
        }


        //ServerDataType playerData[2];
        sf::Packet serverData;
        sf::Uint8 mapSeed = rand() % 1000 + 1;
        sf::Uint8 player1ID = 1;
    
        serverData << player1ID << mapSeed;

        if (clients[0].send(serverData))
        {
            //error
        }

        

    }
```

Obviously this isn't perfect but I am just trying to make it simple to check for sends.
My client code is this

```
    sf::Packet serverData;
    std::size_t received;
    sf::Uint8 mapSeed;
    sf::Uint8 playerID;

    sf::TcpSocket serverSocket;
    sf::Socket::Status status= serverSocket.connect("127.0.0.1", 1000);;

    while (status != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            //error...
        }
    }

    

    if(serverSocket.receive(serverData))
    {
        //error
    }

    serverData >> playerID >> mapSeed;
```

My output from cout is

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't show how you output the received data

Comment: Sorry its just using std::cout

Comment: You should not `cout` uint8